# React native navigation: get state in children Screens from refNavigationContainer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, amplitude-analytics

I'm trying to set some conditions on the React Navigation headers (for example, if the cart contains items and you want to go back to the home screen, display an alert, and empty cart). The cart is managed in Redux.

How do I get the "currentRouteName" constant to use it as a conditional in "DrawerStack" for example?

I try to use redux to store this value, but it crashes the app.

Also, I don't know why but also the tracking event for amplitude is crashing my app too.

Thanks for the help!

The structure of my screens goes as follows:

```js
<NavigationContainer
            ref={navigationRef}
            onReady={() => {
                SplashScreen.hideAsync();
                routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name;
            }}
            onStateChange={() => {
                const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
                const currentRouteName = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name;
                if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
                    routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
                    trackAmplitudeEvent("Route",
                         {
                             name: currentRouteName,
                             ...restaurantProfileId && {restaurantProfileId}
                         })
                }
            }}
        >
           

--------------

<Drawer.Navigator
            drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
            screenOptions={{
                drawerPosition: "right",
                drawerActiveTintColor: "#fff",
                drawerInactiveTintColor: "#3D3D3D",
                drawerActiveBackgroundColor: foodhiRed,
                drawerLabelStyle: { fontSize: 16, marginLeft: -20 }
            }}>
            <Drawer.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeStack}
                options={{
                    drawerIcon: ({ color }) => <View><Ionicons name="home-outline" size={26} color={color} /></View>,
                    headerTitle: () => (
                        <Text
                            onPress={() => {
                                if (cartItems.length > 0) {
                                    Alert.alert(
                                        "Warenkorb wird geleert",
                                        "Wenn du zum Hauptmenü zurückkehrst, wird der Warenkorb zurückgesetzt",
                                        [
                                            {
                                                text: "Ja", onPress: () => {
                                                    dispatch(emptyCart());
                                                    navigation.popToTop();
                                                },
                                                style: "default"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                text: "Abbrechen",
                                                style: "cancel"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    )
                                } else navigation.popToTop();
                            }}
                            style={{
                                fontSize: 24,
                                color: "#fff",
                                fontFamily: 'Rubik_600SemiBold',
                            }}>
                            Foodhi
                        </Text>
                    ),
                    headerTintColor: "#fff",
                    headerShadowVisible: false,
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: foodhiGreen,
                    },
                    headerLeft: () => {
                        if (screenName !== "StoresIndex") {
                            return (
                                <Pressable onPress={() => emptyCartAlert()}>
                                    <Icon name="chevron-left" color="#fff" size={32} style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }} />
                                </Pressable>
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                            onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}>
                            <Icon name="menu" size={30} color="#fff" />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    ),
                }}
            />
           
        </Drawer.Navigator >
```

Comment: Put your crash details and ping me down there.

Comment: On Sentry I get NSRangeException RNSScreen

*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]

Thread 9 name:   Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.AmplitudeReactNativeQueue
Thread 9 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x1d5c13674 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib               0x1e63771ac pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                     0x19f774c8c abort + 180
3   libc++abi.dylib                       0x1e62b6b8c abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                       0x1e62a6a80 demangling_terminate_handler() ..

Comment: Did you manage to take a look by any chance?